# how many ways are there to add a new column to a data frame RDD in Spark API?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can think of one only using withColumn():

```
val df = sc.dataFrame.withColumn('newcolname',{ lambda row: row + 1 } )
```

but how would I generalize this to Text data? For example of my DataFrame had

strning values say "This is an example of a string" and I wanted to extract the

first and last word as in val arraystring : Array[String] = Array(first,last)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the thing you're looking for?

```
val sc: SparkContext = ...
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._

val extractFirstWord = udf((sentence: String) => sentence.split(" ").head)
val extractLastWord = udf((sentence: String) => sentence.split(" ").reverse.head)

val sentences = sc.parallelize(Seq("This is an example", "And this is another one", "One_word", "")).toDF("sentence")
val splits = sentences
             .withColumn("first_word", extractFirstWord(col("sentence")))
             .withColumn("last_word", extractLastWord(col("sentence")))

splits.show()
```

Then the output is:

```
+--------------------+----------+---------+
|            sentence|first_word|last_word|
+--------------------+----------+---------+
|  This is an example|      This|  example|
|And this is anoth...|       And|      one|
|            One_word|  One_word| One_word|
|                    |          |         |
+--------------------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create a simple DataFrame, stored into a partition directory
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(range(1, 6))\
                                   .map(lambda i: Row(single=i, double=i * 2)))
df1.save("data/test_table/key=1", "parquet")

# Create another DataFrame in a new partition directory,
# adding a new column and dropping an existing column
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(range(6, 11))
                                   .map(lambda i: Row(single=i, triple=i * 3)))
df2.save("data/test_table/key=2", "parquet")

# Read the partitioned table
df3 = sqlContext.parquetFile("data/test_table")
df3.printSchema()
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html